# psql: warning: extra command-line argument ignored

Tags: psql

I'm trying to execute a script to create a role in postgres

```
$PSQL_CLIENT "host=$servername user=$DB_POSTGRES_USERNAME dbname=postgres password='$DB_PASSWORD'"
```

the issue is with the password it has 6 words like(alpha beta charlie) and whitespaces and I'm not allowed to change it

I also tried:

```
$PSQL_CLIENT "host=$servername user=$DB_USERNAME dbname=postgres password=/"$DB_PASSWORD"/"
```

everytime I'm trying to connect I'm seeing this error

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "password content" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "password content" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "password content" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "password content," ignored
```

I think something has to be changed at `password=/"$DB_PASSWORD"/"` not sure what exactly needs to be done to read the password properly. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) says:

> To write an empty value, or a value containing spaces, surround it with single quotes, for example `keyword = 'a value'`.

So your command should work well for passwords containing spaces. You will still have a problem if your password contains `'` or `\`, because

> Single quotes and backslashes within a value must be escaped with a backslash, i.e., `\'` and `\\`.

So you need to use

```
IFS='' escapedpwd=$(echo "$DB_PASSWORD" | sed -e "s/\([\']\)/\\\\\1/g")
$PSQL_CLIENT "host=$servername user=$DB_POSTGRES_USERNAME dbname=postgres password='$escapedpwd'"
```

Comment: my password doesn't contain any ' or \ ,  those are just some words and there are no special characters. still tried with your suggestion, it did not work either

Comment: Describe "did not work". What is the password that gets sent? Debug by using `echo` instead of `psql`.

Comment: yes I did verify with echo, I'm getting it from aws ssm parameter store
the only issue is its not able to read properly and the password is similar to this "alpha beta charlie echo delta xray" with different words

Comment: Perhaps your `PSQL_CLIENT` is a shell script that does not escape such strings well.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I got this sorted out by adding '${DB_PASSWORD}'